# Submodules of a module over an arbitrary product of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $I$ be a nonempty set. For each $i\in I$, let $R_i$ be a ring. Then let
$$R=\prod_{i\in I}R_i$$
be the product ring. For each $i\in I$, let $M_i$ be a right $R_i$-module. Recall that, for each $i\in I$, we have the canonical ring homomorphism
$$ R\to R_i \\ (r_i)_{i\in I}\mapsto r_i,$$
through which $M_i$ inherits a right $R$-module structure. Then let
$$M=\prod_{i\in I}M_i$$
be the direct product right $R$-module. Recall that, for each $i\in I$, we have the canonical right $R$-module homomorphism
$$\pi_i:M\to M_i\\ (m_i)_{i\in I}\mapsto m_i.$$
We are interested in the following claim:

> for every right $R$-submodule $L$ of $M$, we have $$L=\prod_{i\in I}\pi_i (L).$$

The "$\subseteq$" part of the above claim is the obvious one. In fact, it would hold if, for each $i\in I$, $M_i$ were a right $R$-module (instead of the stronger assumption that $M_i$ is a right $R_i$-module). The "$\supseteq$" part isn't too hard when $I$ is finite, but I'm stuck in proving this direction when $I$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.  For instance, consider the submodule $L=\bigoplus M_i\subseteq \prod M_i=M$.  For each $i$, $\pi_i(L)=M_i$, but $L$ is not the entire product $\prod M_i$ as long as infinitely many of the $M_i$ are nonzero.